# Solidworks PDM Launching Excel with Parameters

Tags: excel, solidworks

I have a Solidworks PDM transition that launches a particular Excel sheet that has a Workbook_Open routine that receives a parameter passed in from PDM. That parameter is the %folderpath% of the file being transitioned in PDM. The Excel routines run fine. However, Excel is trying to do too much with the passed in path. After the routine in Excel runs, an Excel dialog is throw as shown here: [image: Excel error message]

Excel is mashing the passed in path with an .xlsx extension (its running a .xlsm file). Here is the command line being executed in PDM "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE""C:\Users\guy\Desktop\TEST FOLDER RENAME.xlsm" /e/ %FolderPath% where the full folder path is C:\PTI\ECO\General\CR-0023482. Any ideas on why Excel is throwing this message and is there a way to suppress/stop it?

Comment: I did some research and found that Excel has issue with long file names and changed the path of the file being opened by PDM. Only 100 characters long. Same issue. I noticed if the path to the file being handed in has a space in the path the message appears twice, once with the first word before the white space and once with the word after the white space in the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it is subtle. The command line in PDM's transitions action cannot have a space between the called spreadsheet and the passed in parameter. This argument works. "C:\Temp\F-Rename.xlsm"/e/%FolderPath% vs. "C:\Temp\F-Rename.xlsm" /e/%FolderPath%.

Comment: For PDM admins - this functionality opens a whole new world of automation without having to create Add-ins.  Excel can access the PDM API  and the SW API as well. Limitless possibilities without the need for an Add-in.